# Data Visualisation - Mesh Plot

Tags: data-visualization

Please feel free to migrate me to whatever platform best suits this question best. I just find myself in a bit of loose end looking for examples of such plots in R or Latex.

If someone could help, would they be able to identify how this plot was produced and with which software? More specifically, a mesh structure representing a self-organising map.

Iterative would be amazing. But it doesn't have to be.

[image]

The reference for the plot is: https://algobeans.com/2017/11/02/self-organizing-map/. All help and direction appreciated.

https://annalyzin.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/som-iterateanimate.gif?w=620

Comment: This was produced in `R`.  Just about any plotting software created after the 1950's could create it, though, because it's just a bunch of points and line segments, likely produced by the `R` functions `points` and `lines`.

Comment: Hi @whuber. You're right. It's far from cutting edge visuals. However, would you be aware of somewhere I could find a similar reproducible R example for the static graph, or the iterative GIF?

Comment: Consider asking on [SO].  But once you have created a suitable data structure, this plot can be created with two lines of code, so you might consider it a good exercise in learning `R` if it's new to you.

Comment: Here's a working example. `X <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list(c(70, 210, 20, 150, 1), 
                                c(120, 160, 10, 100, 2), 
                                c(75, 200, 25, 50, 3)),
                           function(p) cbind(data.frame(Component=p[5]), 
                                             as.data.frame(t(matrix(rnorm(2*p[4], p[1:2], p[3]), 2))))));
plot(X$V1, X$V2, col=c("Yellow", "Green", "Black")[X$Component], pch=19,
     xlab="Blue value", ylab="Green Value", main = "Iteration 1");
with(subset(X, Component==3), lines(V1, V2))`

Comment: Thank you. Genuinely appreciate your help :)